# Индексаторы в JS

Tags: javascript, индексация

В C# можно определить индексатор для какого-то объекта:

```cs
public DataRow this[Int32 Index] {
    get {
        return list[Index];
    }
}
```

В JS есть что-то подобное?
К объекту мы же можем обратиться и как `_object.id` и как `_object["id"]`. Можно ли сделать так для класса в JS?

Comment: в яваскрипте нельзя перегрузить то, что будет выполняться при обращении к свойству с помощью bracket notation. Можно воспользоваться `Proxy` но тогда надо будет делать это для каждого объекта отдельно

Comment: Интересно, а зачем вам это понадобилось?

Answer (score 1):

#### На данный момент индексаторы в Java Script не существуют.

Но в ES6 (2015) был добавлен класс `Proxy`, с помощью которого можно что-то подобное реализовать:

#### Как это все реализовать?

Для начала создадим некий класс `Entity` в котором попробуем определить индексатор. Предупреждаю, что индексатором будет являться не экземпляр класса, а какое-то его свойство к примеру `data`.

```js
class Entity {
    data = [];
}
```

Так как в нашем индексаторе должно меняться не само свойство, а его элементы сделаем его только читабельным:

```js
class Entity {
    #data = [];
    get data() {
        return this.#data;
    }
}
```

Теперь надо применить свойства [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Экземпляр класса `Proxy` ("Заместитель") будет заменять наше свойство копируя его параметры, функции и все остальное и при этом зафиксировать доступ к любым свойствам или методам. Вот как это выглядит:

```js
class Entity {
    #data = [];
    get data() {
        return new Proxy(this.#data, {
            get(target, property, receiver) {
                // При чтении Proxy выполнит эту функцию
            },
            set(target, property, value, receiver) {
                // При записи Proxy выполнит эту функцию
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Поскольку мы определили функции `Proxy.get()` и `Proxy.set()` при запросе к какому-нибудь свойству у нас будут срабатывать они вместо "заводских", соответственно мы должны написать метод записи и чтения в них.

```js
class Entity {
    #data = [];
    get data() {
        return new Proxy(this.#data, {
            get(target, property, receiver) {
                const result = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
                // действия при чтени
                return result;
            },
            set(target, property, value, receiver) {
                const result = Reflect.set(target, property, value, receiver);
                // действия при записи
                return result;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Да, `Proxy.set()` так же возвращяет `Boolean` значение исходя из того удачно ли прошел запись или нет, а `Reflect.set` нам и будет дать это `Boolean` значение. Подробнее про [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect).

#### Немного оптимизации

Чтобы каждый раз при обращении к свойству не создавалось новый "Заместитель", можно переместить все это в тело класса:

```js
class Entity {
    #data = [];
    #dataProxy = new Proxy(this.#data, {
        get(target, property, receiver) {
            const result = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
            // действия при чтени
            return result;
        },
        set(target, property, value, receiver) {
            const result = Reflect.set(target, property, value, receiver);
            // действия при записи
            return result;
        }
    });
    get data() {
        return this.#dataProxy;
    }
}
```

#### Дефекты

В таком индексаторе мы можем отслеживать изменения, но не сможем определить именно к какому элементу они относятся. В аргумент `property` мы будем получать как и ключи измененных элементов (к примеру `"0"`) так и свойства массива (к примеру `"length"`, `Symbol.iterator`) и методы.

#### Живой пример

Теперь посмотрим как все это работает.

```js
class Entity {
    #data = [];
    #dataProxy = new Proxy(this.#data, {
        get(target, property, receiver) {
            const result = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
            console.warn(`Чтение '${property.toString()}'.`);
            return result;
        },
        set(target, property, value, receiver) {
            const result = Reflect.set(target, property, value, receiver);
            console.warn(`Запись '${property.toString()}' на ${value}.`);
            return result;
        }
    });
    get data() {
        return this.#dataProxy;
    }
}

const entity = new Entity();
entity.data[0] = 1;
entity.data[1] = entity.data[0];
entity.data.push(entity.data[0] + entity.data[1]);
for (const item of entity.data) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper {
  inset: 0;
  max-height: unset;
}
```

Comment: Я знаю, что вопрос 3-летней давности, но эта тема действительно нуждается в объяснении. Когда-то, когда сам изучал, искал на разных сайтах и особенно тут и не нашел ничего подобного.

Comment: _при использовании for of сначала выполняется чтение всех индексов, потом параметра length который не является числом._ - что это значит?

Comment: @Grundy эта строка самому что-то не нравился. Перефразировал. Взгляните сейчас.

Comment: плохо. чтение `length` - это особенность реализации итератора по массиву. В общем случае length не будет запрашиваться. Только сам итератор

Comment: и пример какой-то странный. Ты записываешь `0.5` ключ, но потом теряешь его

Comment: @Grundy в примере с частью `0.5` я хочу показывать что мы зафиксируем именно те изменения в которых ключ является целым числом (int) и не реагируем на числа с дробью (float). А по поводу `length` [вот минимальный пример](https://codepen.io/eccs0103/pen/zYLNRZE). Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я неправильно реализую из-за которого используется `length`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141908/discussion-between-grundy-and-eccs0103).